# Using Python to connect to Impala database (thriftpy error)

Tags: python, python-3.x, impala, impyla, ibis

What I'm trying to do is very basic: connect to an Impala db using Python:

```
from impala.dbapi import connect

conn = connect(host='impala', port=21050, auth_mechanism='PLAIN')
```

I'm using Impyla package to do so. I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/thriftpy/transport/socket.py", line 96, in open
    self.sock.connect(addr)
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alaaeddine/PycharmProjects/test/data_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    conn = connect(host='impala', port=21050, auth_mechanism='PLAIN')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/impala/dbapi.py", line 147, in connect
    auth_mechanism=auth_mechanism)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 758, in connect
    transport.open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/thrift_sasl/__init__.py", line 61, in open
    self._trans.open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/thriftpy/transport/socket.py", line 104, in open
    message="Could not connect to %s" % str(addr))
thriftpy.transport.TTransportException: TTransportException(type=1, message="Could not connect to ('impala', 21050)")
```

Tried also the Ibis package but failed with the same thriftpy related error.

In Windows using Dbeaver, I could connect to the database using the official Cloudera JDBC connector. My questions are:

- Should pass my JDBC connector as parameter in my connect code? I have made some search I could not find something pointing at this direction.
- Should I try something else than Ibis and Impyla packages? I had experienced a lot of version related issues and dependencies when using them. If yes, what would you recommend as alternatives?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:
I used pyhive package instead of Ibis/Impyla. Here's an example:

```
#import hive from pyhive
from pyhive import hive

#establish the connection to the db
conn = hive.Connection(host='host_IP_addr', port='conn_port', auth='auth_type', database='my_db')

#prepare the cursor for the queries
cursor = conn.cursor()

#execute a query
cursor.execute("SHOW TABLES")

#navigate and display the results 
for table in cursor.fetchall():
    print(table)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your impala domain name must not be resolving. Are you able to do `nslookup impala` in command prompt? If you're using Docker, you need to have the docker service name in docker-compose as "impala" or have "extra_hosts" option. Or you can always add it to /etc/hosts (Windows/Drivers/etc/hosts) as `impala 127.0.0.1`

Also try 'NOSASL' instead of PLAIN sometimes that works better with security turned off.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple method, connecting impala through impala shell using python.

```
    import commands
    import re
    query1 = "select * from table_name limit 10"
    impalad = str('hostname')
    port = str('21000')
    database = str('database_name')
    result_string = 'impala-shell -i "'+ impalad+':'+port +'" -k -B --delimited -q "'+query1+'"' 
    status, output = commands.getstatusoutput(result_string)
    print output
    if status == 0:
            print output
    else:
            print "Error encountered while executing HiveQL queries."
```